# Program in Java to read any file and find a substring, and replace it with another string

Tags: java, xml, string

This is the code I've come through. What I am trying to reach through this is to edit an XML file and code and put special characters like | (pipe) in place of &#x7c and so on.

```
    class FileReplace
    {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        public void  doIt()
        {
            try
            {
                File f1 = new File("C:/file.xml");
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                while (line = br.readLine() != null)
                {
                    if (line.contains("&#x7c;"))
                        line = line.replace("&#x7c;", "|");
                    lines.add(line);
                }


                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for(String s : lines)
                     out.writeline(s);
                out.flush();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally {
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        out.close()
        }

        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
            fr.doIt();
        }
}
```

I tried and reached following error, 
[image]
Please help. Thanks

Comment: why don't you try it then tell us if it worked or not ?

Comment: I tried and got following error modifier.java:42: error: reached end of file while parsing } ^

Comment: then please post the full stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Work

**FileReplace.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileReplace {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    public void doIt() {
        File f1=null;
        FileReader fr=null;
        BufferedReader br=null;
        FileWriter fw=null;
        BufferedWriter out=null;
        try {
            f1 = new File("src/test.xml");
            fr = new FileReader(f1);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("&#x7c;"))
                    line = line.replace("&#x7c;", "|");
                lines.add(line);
            }

            fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for (String s : lines)
                out.write(s);
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            out.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe)

            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
}
```

**test.xml before running program**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove&#x7c;</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder&#x7c;</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**test.xml after running program**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove|</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder|</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Let me know if u face any issues .....

Answer (score 0):

Change `Close()` to `close()` and close your readers / writers in a `finally` block and it will work.

You can also use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score -1):

Your class is missing the closing brace `}`, so the class file can't be parsed.

Also, in your `doIt()`, don't call `close()` on any of the readers or writers in the try-block. The finally will handle this nicely for you. :)

Right now, you're closing it in the try, then when everything has completed without errors, trying to close an already closed reader or writer again in the finally block.

Comment: yea i added the closing brace. But still had the error. I also removed the close() operation from try block. I have added the image of error in the question.

Comment: if you were right then he should get this type of error : `Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

Comment: @Salah: In Eclipse, yes. Using `javac` you get exactly the OP's error.